# How to disable/deactivate a SalesForce User through SOAP API?

Tags: api, soap, salesforce

I want to disable a User programmetically by using SOAP API. How can I do that? I am using Partner API and I have Developer edition. I have manage users persmissions set. I have gone through [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) link. I am looking for code which can help me disable/deactivate a User.

This is my code:

```
import com.sforce.soap.partner.Connector;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.QueryResult;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

public class DeactivateUser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();

        config.setUsername("waprau@waprau.com");
        config.setPassword("sjjhggrhgfhgffjdgj");

        PartnerConnection connection = null;

        try {
            connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
            QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Username, IsActive from User");

        if (queryResults.getSize() > 0) {
            for (SObject s : queryResults.getRecords()) {
                if(s.getField("Username").equals("abcd@pqrs.com")){
                    System.out.println("Username: " + s.getField("Username"));
                    s.setField("IsActive", false);
                }
                System.out.println("Username: " + s.getField("Username") + " IsActive: " + s.getField("IsActive"));
            }
        }
        } catch (ConnectionException ce) {
            ce.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is output:

```
Username: waprau@waprau.com IsActive: true
Username: jsmith@ymail.net IsActive: false
Username: abcd@pqrs.com
Username: abcd@pqrs.com IsActive: false
```

However in UI when I go to My Name > Setup > Manage Users > Users, it always show 'Active' check box for user abcd@pqrs.com selected :-(

Comment: I think you forgot to call `connection.update` after **set** `IsActive`, read this > http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_update.htm

Comment: Thanks Martin Borthiry for pointing what was missing. I will look into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually sending the update back to Salesforce - you're just setting `IsActive` to false locally. You will need to use a call to `PartnerConnection.update(SObject[] sObjects)` in order for Salesforce to reflect your changes, like so:

```
try {
    connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
    QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id, Username, IsActive from User");

    if ( queryResults.getSize() > 0 ) {
        // keep track of which records you want to update with an ArrayList
        ArrayList<SObject> updateObjects = new ArrayList<SObject>();
        for (SObject s : queryResults.getRecords()) {
            if ( s.getField("Username").equals("abcd@pqrs.com") ){
                System.out.println("Username: " + s.getField("Username"));
                s.setField("Id", null);
                s.setField("IsActive", false);
            }
            updateObjects.add(s);    // if you want to update all records...if not, put this in a conditional statement
            System.out.println("Username: " + s.getField("Username") + " IsActive: " + s.getField("IsActive"));
        }
        // make the update call to Salesforce and then process the SaveResults returned
        SaveResult[] saveResults = connection.update(updateObjects.toArray(new SObject[updateObjects.size()]));
        for ( int i = 0; i < saveResults.length; i++ ) {
            if ( saveResults[i].isSuccess() )
                System.out.println("record " + saveResults[i].getId() + " was updated successfully");
            else {                        
                // There were errors during the update call, so loop through and print them out
                System.out.println("record " + saveResults[i].getId() + " failed to save");
                for ( int j = 0; j < saveResults[i].getErrors().length; j++ ) {
                    Error err = saveResults[i].getErrors()[j];
                    System.out.println("error code: " + err.getStatusCode().toString());
                    System.out.println("error message: " + err.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
} catch (ConnectionException ce) {
        ce.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks JCD for detailed reply with code. I will try to implement it. Thanks again.

Comment: Hello JCD, I am getting following errors from else block: 

record null failed to save, 
error code: MISSING_ARGUMENT, 
error message: Id not specified in an update call

Comment: See my updated answer, you need to modify your query to include the Id field. This will let Salesforce know which records you are updating when you push the changes: `QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id, Username, IsActive from User");`

Comment: Thanks JCD for quick reply. I did as you stated. Now its giving exception in catch block which is:
com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: A duplicate value was specified for field 'Id' in object 'User', duplicate value '005E0000001fVU1IAM' prior value '005E0000001fVU1IAM'

Comment: Exception com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException is being shown at line SaveResult[] saveResults = connection.update(updateObjects.toArray(new SObject[updateObjects.size()]));

Comment: For whatever reason, Salesforce doesn't seem to like it when you pass the `Id` field with the updated fields as well as in the call to `setId()`. I just updated my answer - you should be able to save the record by setting `Id` to null: `s.setField("Id", null);`

Comment: No problem. To make an update to a record in another context (i.e. where you know the Id of the record you want to update, but you're creating the `SObject` in your code manually as opposed to a result from your `QueryResult` object), you won't have to set the Id field to null; instead, you would just include a call to `SObject.setId(String Id)`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to directly work with the user record without the SOQL query if you already know the Id.

```
SalesforceSession session = ...;

sObject userSObject = new sObject();
userSObject.Id = "00570000001V9NA";
userSObject.type = "User";
userSObject.Any = new System.Xml.XmlElement[1];

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement fieldXmlElement =  xmlDocument.CreateElement("IsActive");
fieldXmlElement.InnerText = bool.FalseString;
userSObject.Any[0] = fieldXmlElement;

SaveResult[] result = session.Binding.update(new sObject[] { userSObject });
foreach(SaveResult sr in result)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sr.success + " " + sr.id);
    if(!sr.success)
    {
        foreach(Error error in sr.errors)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(error.statusCode + " " + error.message);
        }
    }
}
```