# Deactivate salesforce user

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce

After looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508026/how-to-disable-deactivate-a-salesforce-user-through-soap-api) post, it looks like it is possible to deactivate a user using the partner API and Java. How would one go about using the REST API and Python to remove a license for a user within an organization (so by using the enterprise api)? Is this possible using [this](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce) framework?

Answer (score 2):

You can deactivate the user via standard Salesforce REST API that [updates a record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm) where the type of record is [User](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm). With simple-salesforce, it might look something like this:

```
sf.User.update('005...',{'IsActive': False})
```

where `005...` is an Id of your User record (truncated for the sake of example). You don't need to explicitly remove the license - Salesforce will automatically "free" the license (by no longer counting it as active) when you deactivate the user.